# Create MIDI Program

Tags: midi

I am trying to get some codes from my PC to a Roland BK7M Backing Module to carry out a program change. For all Roland Midi messages there are three codes necessary and for my program change they are as follows;

CC00 : 122
CC32 : 0
PC      : 2

I have been trying to use “generic_midi program_06.ahk” kindly provided by “genmce” more or less as a starting block to try and create a program but I am afraid that I have not even got out of the starting blocks! I will outline the feedback I am getting when I run it.

Firstly I get ”Error, midiInOpen Returned 2” and then “Error, midiInStart Returned 5” , “Right Click pn the Tray Icon Left Click on  MidiSet to select valid midiin Port”

Then up comes the Midi Monitor and from the Midi In Port selection I select ”USB Audio Device “ which is the title given to the BK7M. From the Midi Out Port I selection I select MicrosoftGS Wavetable SW Synth.

I am then left with the two screens under these selections, which contain the following headings;
Event Type_StatB_Ch_Byte1_Byte2. The same headings appear under the two options Midi In Port and Midi Out Port.

In the Midi In Port side I am getting what appears to be a continuous reading for StadB, Ch_Byte1 and Byte2  of  248 , 9 , 0 , 0 with no reading under the Event Type heading. On the Midi Out Port side I am getting no readings at all.

I would very much appreciate any help on this as my knowledge concerning midi is very limited.

Comment: Uhm.. what's the question?  You describe what you're doing, but not what you're trying to accomplish. You want to know what bytes to send to accomplish a program change?

Comment: More information would be handy. Clarification of what would you like to achieve, what environment do you use and what language do youwan to use.